# Why is my code not following the command?

Tags: python

```
def pairs(x):
  for num in x:
    if num == num :
     return x

y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3]
pairs (y)
print (y)
```

this is returning `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3]`
but I want to return `[2,2,3]`
I've tried 3 codes already other than this one
help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain: 1) What is the code supposed to do, conceptually? **Why** is `[2, 2, 3]` the correct answer for this input? 2) How do you intend for the code to work? Do you expect the caller's list to change? Do you want to return a new list? Something else? Please also read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be intended to find all the numbers that exist in pairs in the list. The best way would be (for a sorted list) to just cycle through the list and check successive elements.
Your code just matches if the current number is the same as the current numbers always returns true and returns all elements. A correct Code might be:

```
y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3]
y=sorted(y) # Sorts the given list

def pairs(arr):
    i = 0 # Counter variable
    res = [] #result list
    while i < len(arr)-1:
        if arr[i] == arr[i+1]: 
            res.append(arr[i]) # If the successive elements are the same, add 
                               # it to the result array and since we have already 
                               # checked the next element, increment the counter by 
                               # two
            i+=2
        else:
            i+=1 # If the elements are different we need to check the 
                 # next element as well so increment by 1
    return res
    
print(pairs(y))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But what can I do to make this also happen...pairs([7, 8, 7, 8, 2, 2, 1]) should return [2, 7, 8]. Both should happen. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Why should `7` and `8` be a part of the resulting list?

Comment: The description is unclear. Your definition of "pair" is somehow different than the one I have. If you say that the pair (7,8) is contained two times in the list and so 7 and 8 have to be part of the result I don't understand the expected result in your question. `3` shouldn't be part of the result since `3` has only the pairs (4,3) and (3,3) and these two pairs are not equal.

Comment: I meant that in this list [7, 8, 7, 8, 2, 2, 1], there are two 7, two 8 and two 2. They have pairs so it should be included in the resulting list. It's just that it is rumbled. Hope you get it.

Comment: @gege, as I said it is for a sorted list, so just sorting the list would be enough to get the result. you can use the python `sorted(y)` function to sort the list

Comment: Just for fun some evil stuff. A one-liner with the help of `itertools` from Pythons standard library: `return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([a] * (b // 2) for a, b in ((g[0], len(list(g[1]))) for g in itertools.groupby(sorted(x))) if b > 1))`

Comment: @ Anshumaan Mishra  This is returning [2] only. I'd like to return [2,7,8]                                                                                                   
 def pairs(x):
    i = 0 
    z = [] 
    while i < len(x)-1:
        if x[i] == x[i+1]: 
            z.append(x[i])
            i+=2
        else:
            i+=1        
    return z
y = pairs([7, 8, 7, 8, 2, 2, 1])
y.sort()
print (y)

Comment: @gege as I said add `y=sorted(y)` after declaration of `y` I just tried it, I've even edited the code, I tried with `y = [7, 8, 7, 8, 2, 2, 1]` and I got `[2, 7, 8]


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal`

Comment: I see. What I'm doing is y.sort () that's why it's not working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the element with itself which is always true. Here is the correct logic

```py
y = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3]
filt = []
i=0
while (i< (len(y)-1)):
    if y[i] == y[i+1]:
        filt.append(y[i])
        i+=1
    i+=1    
print(filt)
```